# How can I generate different event from two button columns in gridview?

Tags: asp.net

How can I generate different events from two button columns in gridview?
I want to add two button field: one is Yes and one No and I want to call different server side functions from the buttons.

Comment: Not quite enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean asp:ButtonField, you can use different CommandName to create something you can distinguish, but if you want different events to be fired you need to use a different column type, such as putting an asp:Button in a asp:TemplateField and putting a click or command event handler on those buttons.

Comment: but I want Index number also of the selected button

Comment: you mean the row index? what method are you using from the 2 stated in the answer?